# Volley get request on Android Studio given Client Error

Tags: android, android-studio, android-volley

I have been trying to send a GET request through Volley, but I'm getting client error, the request works fine on postman.Here's the code:

```
 var url = "https://hargrimm-wikihow-v1.p.rapidapi.com/steps"
        val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this@MainActivity)
        val jsonObjectRequest = object : JsonObjectRequest(
            Request.Method.GET,
            url,
            null,
            Response.Listener {
                Toast.makeText(this, it.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()


            },
            Response.ErrorListener {
                Toast.makeText(this, it.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }

        ){
            override fun getHeaders(): MutableMap<String, String> {
                val headers = HashMap<String, String>()
                headers["Content-type"] = "application/json"
                headers["x-rapidapi-key"] =
                    "MY API KEY"
                headers["x-rapidapi-host"] =
                    "hargrimm-wikihow-v1.p.rapidapi.com"
                return headers
            }
        }

            queue.add(jsonObjectRequest)
```

Comment: And what's the error?

Comment: @IvanWooll it say's com.android.volley.ClientError